# How to visually identify the label of each cluster?

Tags: python, python-3.x, scikit-learn, k-means

I am able to identify the cluster label (an integer, 0 to n-1 clusters) and the names of each data point, which is where a lot of tutorials seem to end. However, that's of no use at all unless I'm able to first identify which label visually corresponds to which cluster.

**Question:** rather than having an "X" for the centroid position, I would like to replace it with the label name i.e., 0, 1, 2, 3, or 4. That way I can then pull data points out from the cluster of interest. Any idea how?

The following code is an amalgamation of my own with tutorial code, so I'm sorry for some of their obscure variable names (e.g., "Z", which is not informative).

```
newArray = projected[:, :2]

k = 5
kmeans = KMeans(n_clusters=5)
y_pred = kmeans.fit_predict(newArray)

# Step size of the mesh. Decrease to increase the quality of the VQ.
h = .02     # point in the mesh [x_min, x_max]x[y_min, y_max].

# Plot the decision boundary. For that, we will assign a color to each
x_min, x_max = projected[:, 0].min() - 1, projected[:, 0].max() + 1
y_min, y_max = projected[:, 1].min() - 1, projected[:, 1].max() + 1
xx, yy = np.meshgrid(np.arange(x_min, x_max, h), np.arange(y_min, y_max, h))

# Obtain labels for each point in mesh. Use last trained model.
Z = kmeans.predict(np.c_[xx.ravel(), yy.ravel()])

# Put the result into a color plot
Z = Z.reshape(xx.shape)
plt.figure(1)
plt.clf()
plt.imshow(Z, interpolation="nearest",
           extent=(xx.min(), xx.max(), yy.min(), yy.max()),
           cmap=plt.cm.Paired, aspect="auto", origin="lower")


for i in range(len(meaResultList)):
    plt.scatter(projected[i, 0], projected[i, 1], c=adjustedClassColourList[i], marker=adjustedMEAResultList[i], 
                cmap=plt.cm.nipy_spectral, edgecolor='k')

    
# Plot the centroids as a white X
centroids = kmeans.cluster_centers_
plt.scatter(centroids[:, 0], centroids[:, 1], marker="x", s=169, linewidths=3,
            color="w", zorder=10)
plt.title("K-means clustering (1506 compounds)\n"
          "(Centroids are marked with white cross)")
plt.xlim(x_min, x_max)
plt.ylim(y_min, y_max)
plt.xticks(())
plt.yticks(())
fig = plt.gcf()
fig.set_size_inches(8.0, 8.0, forward=True)
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: No need to repeat the tags in the title or body (edited).

Comment: @desertnaut This now leaves the reader guessing the methodology until they've either gone through the code or checked the tags first.

Comment: People do not just land in the main page of SO and start reading question titles looking for ones to answer; they actually search (or get alerts) about questions with specific tags. So, in fact, the tags are indeed the very first thing getting read in a question; see [Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/should-questions-include-tags-in-their-titles)

Comment: That was an interesting read. I'm glad I'm not the only one who disagrees, but if you want to edit the post, sure thing!